# Is there anything incorrect about this layout, semantically or otherwise?

Tags: html, css, html5

I would like to know if my chosen layout is HTML5 standards compliant, or if I'm using the heading tags incorrectly (or any other tag for that matter)?

**Main Header**

- `<h1>` for website name
- `<h2>` for webpage name
- `<h3>` for website slogan, or should this be `<span>` with styling?

**Main Content/Sidebar Content**

- `<h2>` for every first heading in each `<section>` element (because a level 1 heading is too large), or should this really be `<h1>` with specific styling; e.g. `.panel-ws section h1`?
- `.first` removes unwanted top margin.
- `.panel-ws` adds whitespace (padding).

### Example Code Extracts (OLD; Updated Below!)

```
<header id="page-header" role="banner">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="header-text">
        <h1>Website Name</h1>
        <h2>Page Title</h2>
        <h3>Slogan</h3>
    </div>
</header>

<main id="content" role="main">
    <div class="panel-ws">
        <section id="name1">
            <h2 class="first">Content 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
        <section id="name2">
            <h2>Content 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
        <section id="name3">
            <h2>Content 3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>

<aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">
    <div class="panel-ws">
        <section id="sidename1">
            <h2 class="first">Side content 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
        <section id="sidename2">
            <h2>Side content 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</aside>

#header-text h1
#header-text h2
#header-text h3
.panel-ws section h2
.first
```

### Example Code Extracts (UPDATED!)

```
<header id="page-header" role="banner">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="header-text">
        <h1>Website Name</h1>
        <p>Slogan</p>
    </div>
</header>

<main id="content" role="main">
    <div class="panel-ws">
        <header id="page-title-container">
            <h1 id="page-title">Page Title</h1>
        </header>
        <section id="name1">
            <h1>Content 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
        <section id="name2">
            <h1>Content 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
        <section id="name3">
            <h1>Content 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>

<aside id="sidebar" role="complementary">
    <div class="panel-ws">
        <section id="sidename1">
            <h1>Related Content 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
        <section id="sidename2">
            <h1>Related Content 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</aside>

#header-text h1
#header-text p
.panel-ws #page-title-container #page-title
.panel-ws section h1
.panel-ws section h2
.panel-ws section h3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Site heading

This is not correct:

```
<div id="header-text">
    <h1>Website Name</h1>
    <h2>Page Title</h2>
    <h3>Slogan</h3>
</div>
```

Using `h1` for the website heading is good.

But your page heading (`h2`), which typically is the main content heading, shouldn’t come there, as now everything else in scope of this page heading, not the site heading. The page heading should be part of the `main` element, and also part of a sectioning content element (`article` or `section`).

The slogan should never be a heading (in previous HTML5 version, you could have used a heading together with the `hgroup` element, but this element is now obsolete). Typically it would be a `div` or, if appropriate, a `p`.

#### Content headings

It doesn’t matter if you use `h1` or `h2` (or any other appropriate level) for a sectioning content’s main heading. Always using `h1` would allow you to move sections without having to adjust the heading levels.

#### The sidebar

If the `aside` content is related to the whole website, it should be in scope of the site heading. If it’s related to the specific page only (i.e., the main content), it should be in scope of the page heading (that means: it should be a child of the content’s sectioning element).

Comment: I've changed the position of the page title and also swapped the slogan to a `<p>` element. In response to the sidebar, its content is going to be related to the contents of the `<main>` element. For example, in `#content` I have the device specifications for the LG Nexus 5, and in the `#sidebar`, I would have all devices related to the Nexus 5, such as the Nexus 4, Nexus 10, Nexus 7, other top-tier LG phones, etc. Also, all first headings start with `<h1>`, and I'm going to follow the model of resetting this with each `<section>` or `<article>` element.

Comment: @DylRicho: Regarding your page heading: you should use a `section` (or `article`, if you think it’s appropriate) explicitly, for example instead of the `div.panel-ws`. This one would include all your sub-sections (`name1`, `name2`, …) then. This, of course, only works if the page heading is appropriate for all these sub-sections. If not, your structure should be changed. -- For discussing these things it would be best to see an example with real content, as the heading outline depends on the actual content.

Comment: [Here](http://v9.dylricho.com/temp/) be a semi-real example of this layout in action. The placement of the page title has me undecided as I did like it better in the banner section, even if it doesn't have to be a heading element.

Comment: @DylRicho: In this example, "HTC One S (Z520E)" would be a child section of "Device Specifications" -- is this intended? I feel like "HTC One S (Z520E)" should be the page heading (= a `section` containing all the other content `section` elements) instead.

Comment: "Device Specifications" was intended to be the page heading as it describes the category of the page, while "HTC One S (Z520E)" is supposed to be a subheading as it stems off from the page heading, in order to create a breadcrumb trail.

Comment: @DylRicho: I see. Usually you don’t reproduce the full category tree in the heading outline. The `title` element may contain references to the top-categories, but the page heading should reflect the actual content on that page, not a top category of that content. Anyway, even if you stay with your current headings, "HTC One S (Z520E)" is not heading to the following sub-sections, because they are on the *same* level, instead of being included in the `#device-rank`.

Comment: Would me altering the "Device Specifications" heading to "HTC One S (Z520E) Specifications" (and then removing the "HTC One S (Z520E)" heading) help? I still did prefer the heading above the slogan, however. Is there a reason why the HTML `<hx>` structuring must be so strict/frustrating to follow?

Comment: @DylRicho: If you want to follow [HTML5’s outline algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#outlines), yes. You can play around with this [outliner](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) to see what outline your page creates. It should make sense. Think of the outline as a kind of table of contents: every heading should exactly describe what the following content is about, with the correct nesting/hierarchy. As a general rule: use `section`/`article` for the main content, which include this main content’s heading and the whole content (e.g., sub-sections).

Comment: I think it's probably [as good as I'm going to get it](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/process.py?url=http%3A%2F%2Fv9.dylricho.com%2Ftemp%2F) right now.

Comment: I've just read up on [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/) about untitled elements in the outline, and it states that it's recommended that "each element have a heading, even `<aside>` and `<nav>`." And I can hide the headings if I don't want them visible via CSS `display:none`. I could do that, if necessary? I was concerned about the untitled elements in the outline, until I read that you could hide them and it would still be okay.

Comment: @DylRicho: It’s recommended to have a heading, but it’s not required! And yes, you may hide them via CSS (but make sure that they are still get read by screen readers; otherwise they’d be superfluous ).

Comment: How does [the document outline](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/process.py?url=http%3A%2F%2Fv9.dylricho.com%2Ftemp%2F) look now? Is that better or worse?

Comment: @DylRicho: Overall pretty good. I’d only change small things now, e.g.,: "Date and Time" doesn’t deserve an own section; "Social Interaction and Accessibility Tools" shouldn’t be assembled; I wouldn’t give the footer and the breadcrumbs explicit headings (they probably don’t mean much to visitors). Oh, and `footer` in a `footer` is not allowed.

Comment: In regards to the accessibility, I was just trying to provide a little better compatibility with assistant devices for impaired users. By removing "Page Footer" wouldn't that mess up the 'recent content' headings too?

Comment: @DylRicho: No, the footer would simply be untitled in the outline. But thanks to it being a `footer`, assistive technology may "know" that it’s a footer. But all this is now far away from your original question.

Comment: I see. Thank you for all the help. I have no further issues. :)

Answer (score 3):

In HTML5 `h1` elements can be treated as relative to their semantic container, so it is not bad practice to have an `h1` as the main page header text *and* further `h1`'s for each `section`, `aside`, `article`, etc.

As you've mentioned you would naturally style this with something like `section h1 { ... }`.  I'd recommend making this more general and not depending on `.panel-ws` because you may want to hang it off `main` and `aside` instead to allow for different header text styling in each?

I found a similar question on stackoverflow which you might want to check out too...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405282/how-to-properly-use-h1-in-html5

For the webpage name and slogan, you could group `h1` and `h2` elements inside a parent `hgroup` to ensure that html readers don't parse the slogan as an implicit second level of content.

Comment: Thank you Stephen; you answered my original question. :)